# How to dismiss UIView on tap Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` that is showed every time I press a button in another view

```
@IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView! 

@IBAction func showView(_ sender: Any) {
    view2.isHidden = false
}
```

What I want is to add a tap gesture that allows me to hide view2 every time I tap outside of the view and, since those views are draggable, I want the second view not to be tappable when hidden ( so that if I touch under my view I don't risk to move it.
This is what I tried:

1. ```
   var gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                              selector: #selector(closeView), name: NSNotification.Name("CloseView"), object: nil)


       gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.closeView))
   }
   @objc func closeView() {
       if view2.isHidden == false {
           view2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           view2.isHidden = false
           self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(gesture!)
       } else {
           view2.isHidden = true
           view2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture!)
       }

   }
   ```
2. ```
   let closeTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(getter: view2.isHidden)
       view.addGestureRecognizer(closeTapGesture)
   ```

None of this work, how can I do?

Comment: Make sure you're calling the closeView() function in your code somewhere.

Comment: I called it in my viewDidLoad I didn't put it in my code I'm sorry, but it doesn't work...

Comment: I am not clear of what you wanna do, but did you try setting userInteractionEnabled to false when you hide the view

Comment: @Gihan I want the tap gesture to hide the view when i tap any part of the screen, plus I want the UIView not to be tappable when hidden. Yes I tried, doesn'twork...

Comment: But in the code you share its set to true in the else

Comment: I know, I tried in a lot of ways, doesn't work... the main problem is with the tap gesture that doesn't work at all

Comment: Try the code I posted

Comment: You're including an unnecessary line of code that may be causing problems. When you call the if statement 'if view2.isHidden() == false { ' you have the same line of code 'view2.isHidden() = false in the same if fucntion. Remove that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if you actually tapped outside of view2:

```
    var gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(closeView), name: NSNotification.Name("CloseView"), object: nil)


        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(closeView(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        self.gesture = gesture
    }

    @objc private func closeView(_ tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: view2)
        guard view2.isHidden == false,
              !view2.bounds.contains(location) else {  //We need to have tapped outside of view 2
            return
        }
        view2.isHidden = true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tap gesture should only handle closeView .

```
@objc func closeView() {
        view2.isHidden = true
        view2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        gesture?.isEnabled = false
    }
```

And the the button click to show your view2 should call this.

```
func  showView() {
    view2.isHidden = false
    view2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    gesture?.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Did you add the gesture to the view add it in view did load

Comment: I don't have to add it to view2, I want the view to be hidden and untameable after i tap anywhere (except for view2 and view1) i n the view...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know if I have been clear enough, I'm not english

Comment: self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture!) in viewDidLoad